# How to create a table within a stored procedure using an attribute for the name of the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

That was a long Title but it says it all. I'm trying to make a procedure which creates a table. I want it to be possible to choose the name of the table by writing it in the parameter. I've cut down on some of my code so you can see my problem.

I got so far, but it doesn't work - any ideas?

```
go 
create proc newUser 
@username varchar 
as

execute 'create table '@username'(
id int,
name varchar
)'
```

Comment: 1) Why are you creating a table for each user? 2) `varchar` defaults to `1` without a length specified what lengths should the parameter and field be? 3) If you must do this you would need dynamic SQL. Be sure to use `quotename` to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I can't be sure without knowing exactly what you are building, but chances are you are doing it wrong if you need a proc that creates tables (other than temp tables).

Comment: One issue, you are missing concatenation operators before/after @username. Did you forget those in your code?

Comment: I'm with JohnFx.  If you're going to have multiple, identical tables that are differentiated only by name, add a column to your table with the name and use it in your `WHERE` clauses to pull out only the rows you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code does the job using quotename to avoid SQL injection:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE newUser  
  @username NVARCHAR(1000) 
AS  

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @cmd=N'CREATE TABLE '+quotename(@username)+N'(id INT, name NVARCHAR(1000))';
EXEC (@cmd);
```

Comment: Lets hope Bobby tables doesn't sign up as a user (i.e. this answer is vulnerable to SQL injection - you need to use `quotename`)

Comment: I disagree, this is safe from SQL injection, as stated.

Comment: @Michael - The comment was posted before your edit. Even following your edit it now is free from SQL injection but won't work. The table name can't be parameterised it does need to be concatenated but `'create table ' + quotename(@username) + '( id int, name varchar(100) )'`. Also the parameter type of `@username` should probably be `sysname` and `@sqlCommand` `nvarchar` rather than `varchar`

Comment: @Martin, changed VARCHAR to NVARCHAR, not sure what you mean by table name can't be parameterized, though.

Comment: @Micahel - It will just try and execute the literal string `create table @username( id int, name varchar )` - which will fail as that is not a valid identifier name except for table variables. you might want to see http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#objectnames

Comment: Your attempt to negate SQL injection via parameters and sp_executesql has the side-effect of actually preventing it from running. What you have is now no more effective than the OP's non-working code.

Comment: I am at a loss as to why parameter substitution of @tusername for @tablename does not occur.

Comment: I see, a table or column name cannot be passed in as a variable in dynamic T-SQL. So, I've ammended my answer to just use the quotename form.

Comment: Thanks Martin for that article!